# Problem with Javascript Object Code and jQuery Promise

Tags: jquery, client-object-model

I know that I am just mising something, but here is the issue:

I have created a helper function:

```
    var RADON = window.RADON || {};
RADON.csom = RADON.csom || {};

RADON.csom.GetLookupData = function () {
    var getvalues = function (site, list, field) {
        var xml = "<View><Method Name='Read List' /><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/></OrderBy><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/></IsNotNull></Where></Query>";
        xml += "<ViewFields>";
        xml += "<FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/>";
        xml += "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
        xml += "</ViewFields>";
        xml += "</View>";
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(site);
        this.list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list);
        this.caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
        this.caml.set_viewXml(xml);
        this.items = this.list.getItems(this.caml);
        ctx.load(this.items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function () { deferred.resolve(this.items); }), Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }));
        return deferred.promise();
    };

    return {
        getvalues: getvalues
    };
} ();

RADON.csom.FillDropdowns = function (items, field, dropdowns, cascade, cascadesite, cascadelist, cascadefield) {
    var opts = "<option value='Select...'>Select...</option>";
    var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();
    var unique = "";
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var li = enumerator.get_current();
        if (li.get_item(field) != unique) {
            opts += "<option value='" + li.get_item("ID") + ";#" + li.get_item(field) + "'>" + li.get_item(field) + "</option>";
            unique = li.get_item(field);
        }
    }
    logit("Dropdowns Length: " + dropdowns.length);
    for (var z=0; z <= dropdowns.length; z++) {
        $("#" + dropdowns[z]).html("").append(opts);
    }
};
```

This code is called by another function after SP.js is loaded:

```
    function GetLookupValues() {
    waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Loading Data...', 'Please wait while the Contract is Loaded...', 76, 400);
    RADON.csom.GetLookupData.getvalues(siteurl, "ddl514", "BaseOptionYr").then(
        function (items) {
            RADON.csom.FillDropdowns(items, "BaseOptionYr", ["Period2", "Period3", "Period4", "Period5", "WhatOptionYear"], false, null, null, null)
            lcount += 1;
            if (lcount == 3) { Loaded(); }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            logit("LookupValues Failed 1: " + args.get_message());
        }
    );
    RADON.csom.GetLookupData.getvalues(siteurl , "ddl514", "FundsAvailable").then(
        function (items) {
            RADON.csom.FillDropdowns(items, "FundsAvailable", ["FundsAvailable"], false, null, null, null)
            lcount += 1;
            if (lcount == 3) { Loaded(); }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            logit("GetLookupValues Failed 2: " + args.get_message());
        }
    );
    RADON.csom.GetLookupData.getvalues(siteurl, "ddl514", "FundSource").then(
        function (items) {
            RADON.csom.FillDropdowns(items, "FundSource", ["SourceofFunds"], false, null, null, null)
            lcount += 1;
            if (lcount == 3) { Loaded(); }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            logit("GetLookupValues Failed 3: " + args.get_message());
        }
    );
};
```

My problem is that the first call runs fine if I rem out the other 2. I am using this to populate dropdowns and there are a lot of different dropdowns I am getting data for. I just feel like the problem could be scope related, but not sure. I get the

> "The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed."

error on the other 2 calls

Comment: Have you located the exact line where the errors originate? Which version of jQuery are you using? Anything helpful from Fiddler trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is directly related to your [execution context](http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/) of `RADON.csom.GetLookupData.getvalues` and also the crappy MSDN sample code that is out there for CSOM.

If you tweak your code to get rid of `this` and use a local variable, then `#bind` your `executeQueryAsync` success handler to that variable, you'll create a scope with the correct execution context.

Here's an example:

```
    RADON.csom.GetLookupData = function () {
            var getvalues = function (site, list, field) {
                var xml = "<View><Method Name='Read List' /><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/></OrderBy><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/></IsNotNull></Where></Query>";
                xml += "<ViewFields>";
                xml += "<FieldRef Name='" + field + "'/>";
                xml += "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";
                xml += "</ViewFields>";
                xml += "</View>";
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                var success = function () { deferred.resolve(this); };
                var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(site);
                var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(list);
                var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
                caml.set_viewXml(xml);
                var items = list.getItems(caml);
                ctx.load(items);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                    success.bind(items), 
                    function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); }
                );
                return deferred.promise();
            };

            return {
                getvalues: getvalues
            };
        } ();
```

This code needs to be tested, but it should work.

Comment: Yes, Matt I do believe I tried without the 'this' piece but will give it another go on Wednesday as I am off tomorrow! I normally do not use 'this' for these, but was following a different example to reference using promises which so far are wicked fast!

Comment: A simple test would be to log out `this === window`. You'll know precisely what's going on then when your looking at it inside the console.

Comment: this code unfortunately has an error in the ctx.executeQueryAsync syntax. Trying to figure out what it is...

Comment: The following edits seemed to have worked! Thanks Matt for the second set of eyes!
            var items = zlist.getItems(caml);
            ctx.load(items);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                Function.createDelegate(this, function () { deferred.resolve(items); }),
                Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) { deferred.reject(sender, args); })
            );

Comment: Accepted Captain Needa!

Comment: If you tweaked my code example, feel free to update my answer with your final code.  That'll help everyone in the long run.